# react-redux developer tool is inactive on the extension bar and not showing the state of the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-devtools-extension

I just completed the redux-tutorial and trying to see the state in the redux-devtools. But the redux-devtools is inactive in the extensions bar and when I clicked it it shows menu
"to right, to left etc". When I choose on of the options it show data in the state which is not exist. Here is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import App from './components/App';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux Devtool (chrome extension) not displaying state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882238/redux-devtool-chrome-extension-not-displaying-state) - You probably forgot to [include the required enhancer](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#11-basic-store).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add **REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**  in the `createStore`

```
const store = createStore(
   rootReducer, 
   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );
```